# javascript radio button check it youtube. how to check it

Tags: javascript

i want to auto check the radio button ( public ) on youtube.

here is partial code i got

```
<tp-yt-paper-radio-button name="PUBLIC" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" role="radio" tabindex="-1" toggles="" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-button--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><div id="radioContainer" style-target="container" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"><div id="offRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><div id="onRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><paper-ripple id="ink" center="" class="circle style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">
    

    <div id="background" class="style-scope paper-ripple" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div id="waves" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
</paper-ripple></div><div id="radioLabel" style-target="label" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">Public</div></tp-yt-paper-radio-button>
```

i want to auto check the public radio button.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('PUBLIC');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
    radios[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

not working

also tried

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('tp-yt-paper-radio-button[name="PUBLIC"]');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
    radios[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

not working

new update not working

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('tp-yt-paper-radio-button[name="PUBLIC"]');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
    radios[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            radios[I].checked = true
        }
    }
}
```

i think to make this work, try set the index of the radio ?

```
<tp-yt-paper-radio-button name="PUBLIC" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" role="radio" tabindex="-1" toggles="" aria-checked="false" aria-
```

ok this works code below however the unlisted radio remains checked.

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('tp-yt-paper-radio-button[name="PUBLIC"]');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
radios[i].checked = true;
}
```

and also i dont think it validates or invokes a click just sets it to public. this is why it shows as unlisted still.

=============

new update again working.

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('tp-yt-paper-radio-button[name="PUBLIC"]');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
radios[i].click();
radios[i].checked = true
}
```

i think this did it.
i need to now press the ok button

Comment: updated the code please check. not working

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName function is used to get elements by TAG name. In your case it is `tp-yt-paper-radio-button` and not `PUBLIC`.

EDIT:
I see you updated. In your second case, did you try to use `checked = true`?

Comment: yes still not checking using the 2nd  updated code

Comment: Instead of `this.checked = false`, try something like: `radios[i].checked = true`

Comment: not working. can you  kindly check post1. updated

Comment: probably because in my first comment I misspelled `i`. Please try again with lowercase `i`

Comment: still not working. can you try and debug it your end ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I actually don't have this button on my end :'( Where is that located for you on youtube?

Comment: post1 updated can you check whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('tp-yt-paper-radio-button[name="PUBLIC"]');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
radios[i].click();
radios[i].checked = true;
}
```